# Appcelerator Date picker without the days box calendar

Tags: android, datepicker, appcelerator-mobile

Application type: mobile, Titanium SDK: 3.0, Platform & version: Android 4.1, Device: Samsung S3
when using the date picker i get a picker with three columns (day, month and year) but ALSO i am getting a calendar like box on the right containing the number of days. how can i remove the calendar box and keep the picker columns?? i am compiling against android 3.2 SDK

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <tool-api-level>13</tool-api-level>
    <manifest>
        <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="13" android:minSdkVersion="13"/>
        <!--
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
        -->
    </manifest>
</android>
```

my code:

```
var minDate = new Date();
        var curMonth = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            curMonth = minDate.getMonth();
            curMonth--;
            minDate.setMonth(curMonth);
        }
        var now = new Date();
        this.visitDatePicker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
            type : Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
            maxDate : now,
            value : now,
            minDate : minDate,
            selectionIndicator : true
        });
```

i added a screenshot of what i mean, maybe i will get some replies :)
my problem is the box that appears on the right of the date picker, how can i get rid of it??

[image: Titanium date picker]

Comment: anyone used datepicker before????

Comment: anyway i opened an issue with it for followup https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-1802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok its a bug, see [Android: Add calendarViewShown to picker TIMOB-12539](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-12539) jira issue.
I spend more time debugging and optimizing titanium than actually writing code and business logic. my next project wont be using Titanium for sure....not acceptable